# Dependency Injection of Logger in custom service

Tags: dependency-injection, workflow, symfony4, php-7.2

I can't understand how the Dependency Injection works for custom services in SF 4.3 and PHP 7.2

In a controller, this simple code dumps an object Logger correctly initialized :

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * @Route("/mytest", name="default_mytest")
 */
public function  MyTestLoggerAction(LoggerInterface $logger) {
    dump($logger);

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}
```

But in a custom service called Guards in Guards.php, $logger is a null value :

```
namespace App\Workflow\CompanyDeploying\Transitions\Guards;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Guards {

    private $logger;

    public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function isValid() {
        dump($this->logger);
    }
}
```

i tried with :

- using LoggerAwareTrait but nothing more happen, $logger always null.
- adding @required on getLogger() and setting public to true in services.yml, $logger always null.
- using public function isValid(LoggerInterface $logger) but all code who is asking for this isValid method returns "Too few arguments to function isValid()"
- using a __contruct(LoggerInterface $logger) but anywhere i need this class, the code returns "Too few arguments to function __construct()"

**First Edit**

my services.yaml

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire:      true # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude:  '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags:     ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    App\EventListener\CompanyIndexer:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

I tried to force autowire, autoconfig and visibility in services.yaml

```
App\Workflow\CompanyDeploying\Transitions\Guards\Guards:
    autowire:      true
    autoconfigure: true
    public:        true
```

and add in my Guards.php

```
private $logger;

/**
 * @required
 */
public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function isValid() {
    dump($this->logger);
}
```

But no success. I always dump a null value.

**2nd Edit**

I call the Guard service from an EventSubscriberInterface who are listening to Wokflow event :

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'workflow.company_deploying.enter.mystate' => 'onEnter',
        'workflow.company_deploying.leave.mystate' => 'onLeave',
        'workflow.company_deploying.guard.mystate' => 'guardMyTransition',
    ];
}

public function guardMyTransition(Event $event) {
    $this->event = $event;

    if (! $this->guardFactory(__FUNCTION__)->isValid()) {
        $event->setBlocked(true);
    }
}

protected function guardFactory($guardName) {

    $guard = GuardsFactory::create($guardName);

    $guard->setCompany($this->event->getSubject());
    if (isset($this->entityManager)) $guard->setEntityManager($this->entityManager);
    if (isset($this->previousState)) $guard->setPreviousState($this->previousState);
    return $guard;        
}
```

My GuardFactory initialize a sub-class of Guards.

In the var/cache, i have a getGuardService.php

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\RewindableGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException;

// This file has been auto-generated by the Symfony Dependency Injection Component for internal use.
// Returns the public 'App\Workflow\CompanyDeploying\Transitions\Guards\Guards' shared autowired service.

include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/src/Workflow/CompanyDeploying/Transitions/Guards/Guards.php';

$this->services['App\\Workflow\\CompanyDeploying\\Transitions\\Guards\\Guards'] = $instance = new \App\Workflow\CompanyDeploying\Transitions\Guards\Guards();

$instance->setLogger(($this->privates['monolog.logger'] ?? $this->getMonolog_LoggerService()));

return $instance;
```

I just need to easily use $logger (or any other service) in every class i need without writing ton of codes with a lot of setters.

Thanks for you help.

**Solution**

Dependency Injection doesn't work with this kind of factory call.

Comment: Probably your service is not autowired. Check in your services.yaml if this service is loaded in DI container and that it is autowired and autoconfigured.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added my services.yaml in the original post and things i've done to "force" autowire and autoconfigure.

Comment: How are you using the Guard service? Can you check into the `var/cache` dir if the service is correctly instantiated and the `setLogger` method is called for your service (you should look for a `getGuardsService.php` file)

Comment: Thank you again for answer. I edited my post to add details you asked. I've two ways for this problem : called from an event and using subclass instead of main class

Comment: Ok, presuming that in your `GuardFactory::create` you're calling a `new Guard`, you are recalling the service in the wrong way: with a constructor call, dependent services are not injected.
You need a service container to create a `Guard` instance for you. For example in your event subscriber you can inject the Guard service, or a ContainerInterface (with the Guard service set as public) or a non-static GuardFactory that recalls the Guard service from the `service_container` service.

Comment: Thank you very much Alessandro, the solution is evident now. I was blind with this Factory and need to change this pattern. Thank you.